# permission denied on .gz files on linux

Tags: bash, shell, permissions, chmod

I have some .gz files, of which i want to run a script on. I need these files to remain in .gz format. When I run my script:

```sh
#!#bin#bash
for f1 in $(~/Desktop/hawkfiles17/NG*.fq.gz);
do
  echo "${f1}"
done
```

I want to check the location of the files. The script returns:

```sh
bash: /home/amyhouseman/Desktop/hawkfiles1/NG0921017_EKDN210018957-1A_HN2MGDSX2_L2_1.fq.gz: Permission denied`
```

I have tried using:
`chmod u+x /home/amyhouseman/Desktop/hawkfiles17/NG0921017_EKDN210018957-1A_HN2MGDSX2_L2_1.fq.gz`, but bash returns:

`bash: /home/amyhouseman/Desktop/hawkfiles17/NG0921017_EKDN210018957-1A_HN2MGDSX2_L2_1.fq.gz: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

I'd be grateful if someone could help, I know that you can't execute .gz files, but I'm not sure what else i can do?
I did look through other posts before.

Comment: You have to perform those commands from **root**, perhaps. Try the next commands: ```su root``` or ```sudo su```.

Comment: Please format your code snippets properly. The whole bash script is displayed in a single line, but line endings are significant.

Comment: The expression `$(~/Desktop/hawkfiles17/NG*.fq.gz)` does not make sense. You try to run a gz-file as if it were an executable. Technically speaking, you get the _permission denied_, because there is no x-bit on this file, but even if this were the case, it would not work and you would get something like _exec format error_ or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to check the location of the files.

You're shebang is incorrect, and several other small strings.

Here is your solution:

```sh
$ cat my_script.sh
#!/bin/bash
for item in $(ls ~/Desktop/hawkfiles17/NG*.fq.gz) ; do echo "$item" ; done
```